# Not able to make users with different roles in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I was doing a project on spring boot security. I wasn't able to make users with different roles.
Like, i need one user having a role of admin and other having user and  admin.
i wasn't not able to do that.

I have posted my entity classes
Could someone help me out that how to make a user as admin.

//User Entity class

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="mytable")
    public class User {
        private int id;
        private String username;
        private String firstname;
        private String lastname;
        private int age;
        private String password;
           private Set<Role> roles;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    ...omitted getters and setters
   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName="id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
        public Set<Role> getRoles() {
            return roles;
        }

        public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
            this.roles = roles;
        }
```

//Role Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class Role {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Set<User> users;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should always post whatever problem or exception you ran into so others can help

Comment: here is one of my projects on github that can do exactly what you are looking for though, i have a user and role class. i think the root problem is going to be the referencedColumnName though.

Here's the link: https://github.com/OpenPCM/openpcm-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your Set and move mapping directly to roles variable in your user entity.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName="id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

And do same for roles entity, you can do have your mapping at get method but set has to be initialize.

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```